# call wordpress post content on another external php page

Tags: php, wordpress

public
     |-- index.php (external)
     |-- post-viewer.php (external)
     |-- /WP (wp installation)

I'm trying to call postings from wordpress installation from external page.
I managed to display post title, excerpts, thumbnail and post content from the index page (by following tutorial : http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website).

When I clicked on the post title on index.php my browser get redirected to Wordpress site (which I want to be hidden from public).

How do you make the post content appears on post-viewer.php instead ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Load the WordPress core functions and load trough the get_post option

```
<?php

   require_once("wp-load.php");

   $post = get_post( 12 ); // your post id

   echo $post->post_content;

?>
```

Comment: What I meant was how to display content on page B when you click link on page A.